# PouchDB - Manually managing conflicts

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Is it possible to manage the sync conflicts from the client?

What I mean is, when pouchDB does a sync and detects a conflict, is it possible to get the local doc PouchDB is trying to sync and the last revision of CouchDB doc? If I can get both docs, I can display them to the user and he can choose which version to keep...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're in luck, because this is exactly the problem CouchDB and PouchDB were designed to solve.

Basically you can read up on the [CouchDB docs on conflict resolution](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html).  Everything in there should also apply to PouchDB. (If it doesn't, it's a bug. ;)). The [CouchDB wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts) also has a nice writeup.

**Edit:** so to provide more details, you'll want to fetch the document with `?conflicts=true` (`{conflicts:true}` in PouchDB).  E.g. you'll fetch a doc like this:

```
http://localhost:5984/db1/foo?conflicts=true
```

And get a doc back like this:

```
{
  "_id":"foo",
  "_rev":"2-f3d4c66dcd7596419c76b2498b3ba21f",
  "notgonnawork":"this is from the second db",
  "_conflicts":["2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621"]
}
```

Here I have a conflict introduced from another database, and that database's revision has won (randomly).  This document's current revision starts with 2-, and the conflicting version also starts with 2-, indicating that they're both at the same level of the revision tree.

To get the conflicting version, you just grab the conflicting rev and call:

```
http://localhost:5984/db1/foo?rev=2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621
```

And you get:

```
{
  "_id":"foo",
  "_rev":"2-c1592ce7b31cc26e91d2f2029c57e621",
  "notgonnawork":"this is from the first database"
}
```

So after presenting the two conflicting versions to the user, you can then add a 3rd revision on top of both of these, which either combines the results, or chooses the losing version, or whatever you want.  This next revision will be prefixed with 3-.  Make sense?

**Edit:** Apparently you also need to delete the conflicting version, or else it will still show up in `_conflicts`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198922/680742).

Comment: I think I didn't express my question correctly... The question is more how do you do it. I have a couchdb server with multiple pouchdb clients so when one of my client has a conflict with the server, I get a 409 error (conflict avoidance chapter from couchdb wiki). As PouchDB does the sync transparently, how can I get the conflicting doc (of the server and of the client). In the db.change callback, I only get the error: {status: 409, name: "conflict", message: "Document update conflict", error: true, toString: function}... how to get the docs?

Comment: When you `get` a document, use `conflicts=true` ([link](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Special_Fields)). I've edited my answer with some more details.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the conflicts argument from PouchDB's API! Thanks! BTW, is the first item in the _conflicts array the last conflict recorded?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can always determine the order of conflicts because the `rev`s should be named like '`1-<hash>'`, `'2-<hash>'`, `'3-<hash>'`, etc.